# CollapsingToolbarLayout background image not working

Tags: android, image, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

In my Android app, the background image for the CollapsingToolbarLayout shows ok in device with Android 4.4.2, but not in 5.1. It only displays the colorPrimary. I tried using the src attribute in the ImageView, but same result.

'''

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:titleEnabled="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <!-- acting weird !!! -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivBigImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="@drawable/queen"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_gig_details" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_share_white_48px"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
```

'''

Answer (score 4):

This is how it should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".classes.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorToolbar"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="center"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingTextAppearance.Inverse"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title="@string/flexible_title">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bgImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:minHeight="100dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/bg"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/flexible.example.toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@null"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: sorry, I don't see the difference.

Comment: Give ScrollFlag to image and toolbar as well.

Comment: Do one more thing, change height of appbarlayout to wrap_content and Imageview to wrap_content